# Jquery ajax posting date

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm baffled why my controller is not recieving the startDate parameter.. from the jquery datepicker

My thoughts are it has something to do with the format.

In this scenario I cant force it using the model for form posting.

The parameter is coming into the action as null.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("myAction")',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        data: { startDate: $('#startDate').val(), endDate: $('#endDate').val() },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#updateDiv').html(result);
        }
    });
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult myAction(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
```

Ive also tried;

```
    startDate: $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date())
```

Comment: and if i put `alert($('#endDate').val());` It shows todays date as expected in the `dd/mm/yy` format

Comment: This is a formatting problem, it's very hard to pass a DateTime to the server directly, best receiving in string and then parsing to datetime.

Comment: Try tracing your ajax request in Browser's developer tool. See if date is really being sent to the client in Data.

Comment: I tried, but as its a post method, it seems to be hidden. musefan and @carlosB Solution is a simple work around.

Comment: the thing is, the exact format string .net expect is dependent on the region settings the server is using, one of the ways it can be is something like "dd/MM/yyyy:Thh:mm:ss". A way to check this is by tracing a datetime received in json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will likely be a format problem - I forget the exact causes.

I would suggest changing the controller action parameters to `string` types instead, then you can manual parse them in the correct format, this is the way I always do it and never have any problems since moving to this method.

Something like this:

```
public ActionResult myAction(string startDate, string endDate)
{
    DateTime? startDT = null;
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(startDate))
    {
        startDT = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
    }
}
```

might be better to use `TryParseExact` instead, depends on how you want to handle bad data really

Comment: did you just change mm to MM :^)  This appears to work.. :)! At least half a days work turned out to something useful. Strangely enough I dont need to change the model based form, using the same action while posting datetimes. It seems to recognise it as a string, and parses correctly too. Thanks

Comment: @Doomsknight: I put `MM` from the start. the syntax for .Net date formats and java script data formats differs, so you cannot use the same. I would suggest throwing both in a config class (or in web.config) and reference them in code. Just incase you need to quickly change the formats

Comment: Best use tryParseExact has the data received might be invalid :), and "mm" on that notation is used for minutes not months (just to clarify).

Comment: @CarlosB: Indeed, and I would likely use `TryParseExact` myself, the OP can choose which best suits his needs though. He may prefer an exception to be thrown, or maybe not ;)

Comment: @musefan: Indeed you are right :) it all depends in which way the wind blows :P

Comment: Since it is done in ajax, the effect of it erroring is not noticed. My view unless im wrong, is that if i default it to something else, i am changing the datas date range when it is best to leave it as it was. Yes, mm was minutes, it had me confused for a minute (not a month ;) ). Wasn't sure if I copied it from you, or it was my own implementation when i saw your first answer of using a string.